# Change hover color over sidebar elements in 1.11?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the new version `1.11` we are able to customize VS using `workbench.experimental.colorCustomizations` config, but still I can't manage to change the hover color in file tree of the sidebar, take a look:

[image: visual error]

I have been looking for patterns like `background` or `hover` but I can't find it, I don't even know if it's implemented as this is experimental. Do you know if there is a config to change this an its name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around in the [file which contains the theme constants](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/ea81c98e6d5c089fd97ebcd871b1353bcf79f0a6/src/vs/workbench/common/theme.ts) I don't believe it's currently possible at this stage.

Hopefully in a future release support for this will be added.

Comment: The await will be intense then : (

Answer (score 9):

```json
"list.hoverBackground": "#424d66",
"list.hoverForeground": "#ff6a00",
```